# How to use viroReact in React native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, augmented-reality, react-native-ios, autodesk-arvr

I am working on project in which I've to implement AR technology.

Example

[Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPP4Y93OA5Q&t=59s)

How can I achieve it in React native for both Android & iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Native code(Java, Obj-C, Kotlin, Swift) gives you the best performance, you can write unoptimised code and it’s still fast. Hybrid apps (eg. Ionic) performance are really far behind native apps before optimisation. React Native apps performance fall between both.

Native > React Native > Hybrid

Code sharing between OS:
Due to hybrid apps use webview as a medium, it can achieve maximum code sharing between different mobile OS, the underlying library ensure the consistency.

React Native apps can achieve 100% as well but you will need minor tweaking (inconsistence) to make it even more native to each platform.

Currently you can use Swift to develop Android as well,